# Below code is not returning ,the square of all list numbers

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

As I am trying to get the square of all list numbers by using lambda function.

It is not giving me the correct answer. Can someone help me with this please. I don't want to use list comprehension etc.

I use Python 3.6

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
x=(lambda x:2*x,list1)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## The code

I don't know if this counts as list comprehension to you, but this should work:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]               #your code with some more spacing
x = map(lambda x: x ** 2, list1)   #see below for more on this
for i in x:                        #iterate through this
    print(i)                       #and print each item in it
```

## Map Function

The defenition at [WS3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) is:

> The map() function executes a specified function for each item in a iterable. The item is sent to the function as a parameter.

You can go there for a more complete explanation, but basically, it calls the function on every item in the list, and puts what the function returns for each item into another iterable.